# Map PostgreSql money data type to ORMLite

Tags: java, postgresql, ormlite

What type of data I should define on my java model for PostgreSQL money type?

I know I could use BigDecimal, but it map to varchar(255) on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Do not use the money datatype with Postgres - use `decimal` instead. The money type has lots of problems (e.g. it's locale dependent and thus can introduce problems on different computers, e.g. see here: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2011-11/msg00108.php). And never ever store a number in a character column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that @a_horse's comment provides some good information but I thought I'd add some additional [ORMLite's](http://ormlite.com/) specific details.

You could use ORMLite's `BIG_DECIMAL_NUMERIC` which will store it in Postgres as `NUMERIC`.  You'll need to specify it as:

```
@DatabaseFiled(dataType = BIG_DECIMAL_NUMERIC)
BigDecimal number;
```

If you are set on using the money type, then you can define your own custom persister.  You can date a look at the documentation that front:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/custom-persister

There is also an example project with code which shows how to define a data persister for your custom type:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/data-persister-example

Comment: using @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BIG_DECIMAL_NUMERIC) works well to map BigDecimal to Numeric... I think I'll just use BigDecimal.